# What's the best format to write my functions in?

Tags: coding-style, code-formatting, curly-braces

which format is best practice?

format A

```
function FunctionA () 
{
    while () 
    {
        >>some code<<
    }
    if ()
    {
        >>some code<<
    }
    else if ()
    {
        >>some code<<
    }
}
```

format B

```
function FunctionB () {
    while () {
        >>some code<<
    }
    if () {
        >>some code<<
    } else if () {
        >>some code<<
    }
}
```

Comment: You're about to incite a holy war. In any case: It doesn't matter - it's a matter of taste. There are arguments for both ways. Just be consistent. If you join a project, choose the style that's already being used.

Comment: "Thou shalt make thy program's purpose and structure clear to thy fellow man by using the One True Brace Style, even if thou likest it not, for thy creativity is better used in solving problems than in creating beautiful new impediments to understanding."

Comment: I like format B better but I see both formats being used and a lot of format A in professionally written codes so I was wondering if format A is best practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, as long as you adhere to one style, and when in a project with multiple people agree on one style and all use that style.

Comment: This is the only real answer to this question. Consistency is the only relevant factor. Excellent job not engaging in the most tempting of holy wars. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's all up to your preference. There is no real "best".

I prefer format A because I can put comments in the space provided by the opening braces.

eg.

```
function FunctionA () 
{// this function does some stuff
    while () 
    {
        >>some code<<
    }
    if ()
    {
        >>some code<<
    }
    else if ()
    {
        >>some code<<
    }
}
```

But some people may prefer the format B as it is more compact.

But others may prefer even more obfuscated code like this:

```
function ObfuscatedFunction () {while () { >>some code<<}if (){>>some code<<}else if () { >>some code<< }}
```

Comment: *Sadists* prefer obfuscated code like that. But I agree with the preference for format A...